# Redrawing during drag and drop

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop

I would like trigger the drag target control to redraw itself (via either invalidate or refresh) during the DragEnter and DragLeave events.  The code looks something like:

```
protected override void OnDragEnter (DragEventArgs drgargs)
{
  //-- Set a property that affects drawing of control, then redraw
  this.MyProperty = true;
  this.Refresh(); //-- Does nothing???      
}

protected override void OnDragLeave (EventArgs e)
{
  //-- Set a property that affects drawing of control, then redraw
  this.MyProperty = false;
  this.Refresh(); //-- Does nothing???      
}
```

It doesn't actually redraw the control, the OnPaint method is not called by the Refresh() within these events. Is there any way to do this?  I must not be understanding something here.

**UPDATE:** the answer provided by jasonh doesn't actually work. When using Invalidate() or Invalidate(rect) the control does not actually update. This is being calls *during* a drag and drop action. Any other ideas? Can you trigger a redraw of a control *during* a drag and drop? Thanks!

**UPDATE 2:** I created a sample project and could not get this to **not** work. Sigh...  I finally tracked it down to some code in the OnPaint that was causing the problem. So, this turned out to be more of me not understanding how the debugger worked (it never hit break points in the OnPaint...still don't know why). Invalidate(), Refresh() both work. JasonH gets the answer as it was ultimately correct and also showed how to invalidate just a portion of a control...I didn't know about that.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: My guess is that you didn't set AllowDrop to true.

Comment: Yes, AllowDrop is set to true. The drag-and-drop is happening. Just the redrawing of the control isn't (OnPaint is not called after Invalidate() or Refresh()).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `this.Invalidate()` to get the Form/Control to redraw itself. If you know the specific region, then call one of the overloaded methods to specify what to invalidate. For example:

```
Rectangle toInvalidate = new Rectangle(drgargs.X - 50, drgargs.Y - 50, 50, 50);
this.Invalidate(toInvalidate);
```

That would invalidate an area 50 pixels around the area the drag target is.

Comment: This didn't work.  The question was specifically about doing this during a drag-n-drop event. If it works for you, there must be something I'm doing wrong...<confused>...

Comment: Not sure why I'm being downvoted, since Invalidate does exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: Make sure that the UserControl has the AllowDrop property set to true. I've tested this in a simple project with a string being drawn to the control and it does change color (what I'm testing with) based on whether or not the user is dragging onto the control. Can you post an example of a project that doesn't work so I can help you get it fixed?

Comment: Why would this get a downvote?  Invalidate is the proper way to force a redraw of a control.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you than it is a problem in *your* code, not in this example.

Comment: I didn't down vote this or any answer...not enough rep.  I might be my code, but the call to invalidate didn't work. Maybe it should/does in other situations, but in mine it didn't. I just commented to that effect and indicated I was aware I might be doing something wrong.  Just trying to figure out the problem. I'm creating a sample app to see if I can reproduce in another environment.

Comment: @jasonh, I did create a sample project and figured out the issue. Invalidate does indeed work (as does Refresh), but I got very confused because I was not hitting the break points within my OnPaint code where the problem was occurring and thus, incorrectly concluded that for some reason Invalidate wasn't working when doing a drag and drop.  Well, I learned a ton with this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are three seemingly applicable methods here:

[Control.Invalidate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) - marks the control (region, or rectangle) as in need of repainting, but
doesn't force repainting, the repaint is triggered when everything else has
been taken care of and the app becomes idle.

[Control.Update()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx) - causes the control to immediately repaint if any portions have been
invalidated.

[Control.Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) - causes the control to invalidate, and then update (immediately
repaint itself).

So, Refresh() is the right approach. What I would do is set a breakpoint on the refresh method call and see if/when it's being hit.

Comment: It is being hit. It executes, but doesn't actually cause OnPaint to be called.